# Why is ESLint warning about a semicolon where I think it's useful?

Tags: javascript, eslint

```
    fetch_roles () {
      axios.get('/roles')
        .then((response) => {
          this.is_loaded = true; <-- ES lint hate this semicolon?! 
          this.pageData = response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(`Error: ${error}`)
        })
    }
```

[image]

I get `ESLint: Extra semicolon.(semi)` for the semicolon shown above. Isn't the semicolon good to have there in case we minify?

Comment: It seems like you configured eslint to only require semicolons where absolutely required.

Comment: How would minification affect that line?

Comment: If your concern is minification why aren't you using them anywhere else? It seems odd that you'd have one there and nowhere else. Anyway, you can fix your lint rules, or add a [disabling rule before that line](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi). Or just remove the semi-colon.

Comment: @DaveNewton I mean minifier may "stick" those 2 adjacent lines `this.is_loaded = true this.pageData = response` I have encountered such issue earlier may be the minifier was stupid ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get ESLint: Extra semicolon.(semi) for the above pointed semicolon.

ESLint can be configured to [require, ignore, or forbid optional semi-colons](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi). Your configuration has set them to forbidden.

> Isn't the semicolon better be there incase we minify ?

If minifying causes a problem when optional semi-colons are absent then you need a better minifier.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your linter configuration is currently set up to forbid semicolons.

If you're an expert and can identify potential bugs due to Automatic Semicolon Insertion rules at a glance, you can keep your current rules and delete the semicolon from that line safely.

Otherwise, you might find it more beneficial to change the `semi` rule to require semicolons when appropriate instead, which can prevent hard-to-understand bugs from popping up.

To do this, [change the `semi` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi) to `always` instead of `never`. You'll also need to add semicolons to the following lines:

```
this.pageData = response
```

```
alert(`Error: ${error}`)
```

The existence (or lack thereof) of a semicolon will not really affect minification. If no semicolon on a line is causing a bug due to unintuitive ASI behavior, that bug will be present regardless if the source file is run or if the minified file is run.